# How do I update migrations when upgrading from a Rails 1.2.3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I'm updating a Rails 1.2.3 app to 3.2.1.

I'm trying to figure out how I can update the migration structure to be compatible with the latest version of Rails, so that, ideally, you can just run `rake db:migrate` when setting up the app. Currently, I have solved this by just doing `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=[version_number]` of whatever migration I need to run. If I just run `rake db:migrate`, it tries to rerun all of the migrations from the beginning and it stops (since those migrations have already been run in the db dump I have).

Migrations in the app look like this `001_add_some_model.rb`, `002_add_some_other_model.rb` instead of `20120209182512_add_some_model.rb`.

Does anyone have any experience with this? How can I fix this?

Comment: Wow from 1.2.3 to 3.2.1. Good luck...

Comment: @lucapette Thanks! It's pretty much done, I just want to make running migrations more natural.

Comment: the solution I've seen quite often is "dropping migration and create a new one as a starting point"

Comment: @lucapette Drop all migrations and re-create them?

Comment: See https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/db/migrate/20090823005402_spree_zero_nine_zero.rb it's exactly what I was talking about. It's a good reference project too :)

Comment: @lucapette Great! Thanks for that. If you want to write up an answer with that resource, I'll accept it.

Comment: Done it. Glade you liked the idea!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should *restart* your migrations, drop all the migration you have and create a new migration with definitions of your current models. See [this migration](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/db/migrate/20120831092320_spree_one_two.rb) as a starting example.

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to run all migrations to set up a new database even in an up-to-date Rails 3 app. This is explained in db/schema.rb:

> Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
>   database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
>   system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
>   from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
>   you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what had been suggested, I would create new migrations from scratch.
Start you all your models at the current state and create new migrations for each of them, this way you could still use the power of the migrations later, like adding a column to a table or change a column type.

If you create a singe migration for all your models, [like has been suggested](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/db/migrate/20120831092320_spree_one_two.rb) you'll loose the model track in migrations name.

This is just another way to do it and reflects my own vision.